# mApiClient or mRemoteMediaPlayer is null, so will not proceed can't video to play, no errors

Tags: android, chromecast

```
D/ccl_VideoCastManager( 1923): onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: Ready to play
D/ccl_BaseCastManager( 1923): Successfully added the new BaseCastConsumer listener com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$1@4266ba58
D/ccl_VideoCastManager( 1923): Successfully added the new CastConsumer listener com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$1@4266ba58
D/ccl_VideoCastNotificat( 1923): onStartCommand(): Action: none
D/ccl_VideoCastManager( 1923): RemoteMediaPlayer::onStatusUpdated() is reached
D/ccl_VideoCastManager( 1923): onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated() reached
D/ccl_VideoCastManager( 1923): mApiClient or mRemoteMediaPlayer is null, so will not proceed
D/ccl_VideoCastManager( 1923): RemoteMediaPlayer::onMetadataUpdated() is reached
D/ccl_VideoCastManager( 1923): onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated() reached
```

The `MediaInfo` object is populated correctly I've checked this in the debugger, the `mApiClient` and `mRemoteMediaPlayer` should be created in the `castCompanionLibrary` right? I don't have to do anything with those objects right?

I'll keep testing and update any issues I have but hoping someone can chime in?

Comment: And what is the issue you are running into? That is not an error, just a debug message.

Comment: Oh the video doesn't play on the tv . I'm following the examples on github..  the device sees my image url, and the title of the video I'm trying to play but didn't play it for some reason know

Comment: basically just calling with this line using the CC Library.   

CastManager.startCastControllerActivity(getApplicationContext(), mSelectedMedia, position, autoPlay);

Comment: Since we don't see the rest of your code, it is hard to understand what is going on. You may want to first try the CastVideos-android sample and make sure that runs for you and then compare your code with that to see what you are missing.

Comment: Yeah I know i'm kind of not helping with my inputs.  I finally got the  CCL to work and I missed some things in the manifest that needed to be there.  
This is what it hits, but nothing past this.. it's like it's stuck here.



 `case MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_BUFFERING:
                mPlayPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mLine2.setText(getString(R.string.loading));
                break;`

Comment: My bad Ali.  I was using your cast receiver.. and it plays my video fine.. I'm goign to check on my receiver to make sure it's working correctly.